# ESP8266 RTC memory (for bootcount)

Tags: esp8266, sleep

I'm using an ESP8266 with deep sleep + wake up when `RST` pin goes low.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootcount = 0;

void setup() {
    bootcount ++;
    WiFi.begin("MySSID", "password");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(20);
    }
    // here I send "bootcount" with HTTP request
    ESP.deepSleep(0);
}
void loop() {
}
```

Here `RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootcount = 0;` fails with `RTC_DATA_ATTR` unknown.

**How to get the number of times the ESP8266 has woke up from deep sleep?**

Comment: RTC_DATA_ATTR is for esp32

Comment: Thanks @Juraj, you're right, I think you can post this as an answer. Does this mean it's not possible to count the number of times the ESP8266 has resumed/rebooted from deep sleep? How to save/restore a number in RTC memory?

Answer (score 5):

The ESP8266 RTC has 512 bytes of RAM that persist across restarts but not during power outages. While this RAM isn't persistent across power outages it also doesn't have the write limitations that flash memory has, making it appropriate for frequent writes which don't need to survive power loss.

The ESP32's compiler and software framework make it easy to access similar memory on it using the `RTC_DATA_ATTR` attribute; unfortunately as you found and @Juraj pointed out, the ESP8266's doesn't.

Thankfully the Arduino core for the ESP8266 includes support for reading and writing this area of memory using methods in the `ESP` object.

`ESP.rtcUserMemoryRead()` reads RTC memory and `ESP.rtcUserMemoryWrite()` writes RTC memory. In your case you could do something like this:

```
void setup() {
  uint32_t bootcount;

  if(!ESP.rtcUserMemoryRead(0, &bootcount, sizeof(bootcount))) {
    Serial.println("RTC read failed!");
    while(1)
      yield();
  }

  bootcount++;

  if(!ESP.rtcUserMemoryWrite(0, &bootcount, sizeof(bootcount))) {
    Serial.println("RTC write failed!");
    while(1)
      yield();
  }

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("boot count is ");
  Serial.println(bootcount);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Not quite as convenient as the `RTC_DATA_ATTR` attribute but it still gets the job done.

I changed the type of `bootcount` from your example to `uint32_t` because it should never be negative, and the size of `uint32_t` is independent of the size of `int`.

Because the Arduino core is open source, you can [read the implementation of these functions](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/24c41524dc56c683d8926671bdd639d7411f2815/cores/esp8266/Esp.cpp#L141) if you want to know how they work.